# Drawing with Transparent Paint on Android

Tags: android, canvas, 2d, draw, paint

When I use `Paint` with `Color.TRANSPARENT` on a normal 2D canvas in Android, I don't get any results and my intention was to get rid of some of the contents on the canvas. I mean the contents that I want to dispose of don't disappear.

This is the code for my `Paint`:

```
mPointFillPaint = new Paint();
mPointFillPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPointFillPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
mPointFillPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
mPointFillPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The following `Paint` configuration should help:

```
mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
```

Comment: I have used your code but this code remove some point of below paint object. Like when i draw one line then again i draw another line above last line i draw. And press undo button at my end then i cuts the point of first line where 2nd line draw above the first line. How can i resolve this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I found that using

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
```

or

```
mPaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
```

just made my paint black.

I had another approach which was to introduce a transparent color to my colors.xml

```
    <color name="transparentColor">#00ffffff</color>
```

I opted for the "00ffffff" case but i'm pretty sure that "00000000" will work also, depends on your case.

Final code looks like:

```
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparentColor));
```