# How to erase image with finger in Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I'm developing an app that need the feature in object.

I have an Image A that cover an Image B. With finger I need to erase the Image A to show the Image B.
Erase must follow your finger flowing image A

I'm trying some code but still I couldn't erase the image A. this is the code that i'm using to draw a line on image (_imageToErase is Image A):

```
Canvas canvas;
Paint paint;
float downx = 0, downy = 0, upx = 0, upy = 0;
ImageView _imageToErase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.g_layout);

    _imageToErase = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_to_erase);

    _imageToErase.setOnTouchListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){

    int width = _imageToErase.getWidth();
    int height = _imageToErase.getHeight();

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(25);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    _imageToErase.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();

    switch (action){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            downx = event.getX();
            downy = event.getY();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            upx = event.getX();
            upy = event.getY();
            canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
            _imageToErase.invalidate();
            downx = upx;
            downy = upy;
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This code produce only a line that follow the finger but not erase the image.

How to modify this code to erase the image? Thanks

**EDIT**

The link suggested in comments not solved my problem. Simply add this line:

```
 paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_OUT));
```

not work for me.

Comment: your paint is white. At the very least you need a transparent paint.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing with Transparent Paint on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27982853/drawing-with-transparent-paint-on-android)

Comment: @njzk2 yes I know, and in fact i'm tried with transparent, but simply i can't see the line but the image A is always there.. and that question not work for me

Comment: where do you draw the image that you want to erase? it does not seem to be on the canvas that you erase?

Comment: @njzk2 in onWindowFocusChanged i build Bitmap, create Canvas with that Bitmap and the setImageBitmap on image

Comment: yes, but you are never actually drawing the image on the bitmap. I suspect the image is set as background to your imageview?

Comment: @njzk2 yes image is set like background image to _imagetoerase

Comment: it shouldn't. The image and its background are separate things. You need to draw your image on your canvas in order to be able to erase it.

Comment: You will need to play with PorterDuff Xfer modes. By masking what you draw on a 3rd image which cuts the second one, making the first one be visible under the second one. Maybe I wasn't very clear. But it's not too complicate. And, yes, the "first" image, as suggested by @njzk2 could simply be a background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found a library that works very well for me and implementation is pretty simple

https://github.com/winsontan520/Android-WScratchView

Import library in your project and then in `layout.xml`

```
 <com.winsontan520.WScratchView
  android:layout_width="287dp"
  android:layout_height="212dp"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
  android:adjustViewBounds="true"
  android:scaleType="centerInside"
  android:id="@+id/image_to_erase"/>
```

in `onCreate:`

```
_imageToErase = (WScratchView) findViewById(R.id.image_to_erase);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.img_erase);

_imageToErase.setScratchBitmap(bitmap);


_imageToErase.setOnScratchCallback(new WScratchView.OnScratchCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScratch(float percentage) {
            updatePercentage(percentage);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDetach(boolean fingerDetach) {
            if (mPercentage > 40) {
                _imageToErase.setScratchAll(true);
                updatePercentage(100);
            }
        }
    });
```

and

```
private void updatePercentage(float percentage) {

    mPercentage = percentage;
 //   System.out.println("percentage = "+percentage);
}
```

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 2):

*PaintView.java*

```
public class PaintView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

    private static final String TAG = "PaintView";
    Bitmap Bitmap1, Bitmap2;
    Bitmap Transparent;
    int X = -100;
    int Y = -100;
    Canvas c2;
    private boolean isTouched = false;

    Paint paint = new Paint();

    Path drawPath = new Path();

public PaintView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    this.setOnTouchListener(this);

    DisplayMetrics metrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int width = metrics.widthPixels;
    int height = metrics.heightPixels;

    Transparent = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cake1);
    Bitmap2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cake2);

    c2 = new Canvas();
    c2.setBitmap(Transparent);
    c2.drawBitmap(Bitmap2, 0, 0, paint);

    paint.setAlpha(0);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    paint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
}

private static Point getDisplaySize(final Display display) {
    final Point point = new Point();
    point.x = display.getWidth();
    point.y = display.getHeight();
    return point;
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    System.out.println("onDraw");

    if(isTouched)
    {
        canvas.drawBitmap(Bitmap1, 0, 0, null);

    }
    canvas.drawBitmap(Transparent, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    isTouched = true;
    X = (int) event.getX();
    Y = (int) event.getY();

    paint.setStrokeWidth(60);

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            drawPath.moveTo(X, Y);
            c2.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            drawPath.lineTo(X, Y);
            c2.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            drawPath.lineTo(X, Y);
            c2.drawPath(drawPath, paint);
            drawPath.reset();
            count=0;
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }

    invalidate();
    return true;}}class Point {
float x, y;

@Override
public String toString() {
    return x + ", " + y;
}}
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(new PaintView(this));
}}
```

Comment: would it be possible to calculate the percentage of the Image that has been erased?